# Can I safely lift floorboards and trust that the stud wall can be held by the wall ties or would this risk their stability?

Tags: insulation

[image][image]I am looking to lift floorboards to install insulation on a suspended floor.

However, the stud walls sit flush on top of the floorboards. The stud wall with lath and plaster are offset from the stone and brick load-bearing walls and fixed to them with metal wall ties -which in places, are quite corroded.

Can I safely lift the floorboards and trust that the stud wall and lath and plaster can be held by the wall ties or would this risk their stability?

[image: window area, lath and plaster in bckg]
[image: skirting boards and some wood panels removed]

Comment: Are you saying that you want to pull the floorboards out from under the walls? It would be physically impossible to actually 'lift' the floor while the walls remain on top of it ...

Comment: The only way you could do this is if you cut the floorboards (subfloor?) at the bottom plate of every wall.

Comment: Most wooden walls are nailed to the floor they sit on.  While the nails could be cut or removed, there still might be nails holding the floor to the joists.  I will second @Huesmann comment with adding new supports for the cut section of the floor boards afterwards.

Comment: You're correct—I had assumed the OP would figure out that support was needed after stepping on the boards :)

Comment: Thank you @Huesman and crip659. That is exactly the case. Cutting the floorboard at the bottom plate sounds like a good compromise. The stud walls that run perpendicular to the joists would be well supported by them. How about the ones that run alongside the joists? Is there a way they could be secured/supported, in your view?

Comment: Not sure what your question is there.  To re-support your "put back in place" floorboards, you'll want to put blocking (ideally same height as joists) at the end of any floorboard.  The stud walls will be fine—it's only the floor you need to worry about.  Since you appear to have at least one diagonal wall, some of your blocking may need to be diagonal.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. The end of the floorboards overhang the joists unsupported, but this is by design.  They are for the most part tongue and groove solid continuous planks, so shouldn't be an issue. The stud walls, however, are not attached to the wall, instead are 'floating' held only by metal ties that are embedded in the wall (see the diagram I've upldoaded). Crucially, they also appear to be resting on the overhanging ends of the floorboards. It looks like I would need to build some kind of support for both. A joist or underpinning jack.

Comment: If you're talking about the structure under the window sill, I wouldn't call that stud walls.  That's basically fancy strapping designed to hold a plaster facade in front of a stone wall.  It's still unclear what you're trying to do.  If you want to yank the floor from under it, it will probably just hang there and could be pushed back up later but I would just take it apart up to the window sill then rebuild it.  In my experience things go faster if you don't make them fiddly.

Comment: Are you sure the ends of the floorboards are unsupported? What, they are cantilevered so if you stand near the wall it is the nails further down the board that are supporting you?  Also are you sure the floorboards are supporting what you call studs? They look more like furring strips that don't need a huge amount of support.  Mind you, lath and plaster can be heavy so if the wall ties are corroded the floor might be doing some work.  Your photo shows a small section of bay window perpendicular to joists.  Is your question about the  wall on the left with plaster intact?

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion, @aquaticapetheory. That´s right, dismantling the frame around the bay window shouldn't be an issue like you say. I was showing it for illustrative purposes because the lath and plaster walls seem to be built the same way. I've added another pic of one of the stripped walls for context.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, @jay613. That's right: my question is more about the main walls and whether they would hold.

Answer (score 1):

Repeating what I said in the comments, those aren't "stud walls," they're basically furring for putting up plaster over the rough stone walls. They're not all that solid by themselves and probably not that heavy so if you yank the floor from under them they'll probably just hang there.  *Probably*.  Maybe possibly?  I think.

The ones under the window sills, I would just remove and put back afterwards.  You'll have to finagle floor boards under them when you're done if you leave them in place.  Working under those "walls" building up some foundation and stuff while trying not to destroy them is making your job unnecessarily harder.  It would be less trouble to just rebuild them later.

The taller ones are a bit more tricky because they go above the ceiling.  If you let them hang and then they fall or you knock into them, they munge up your ceiling and now you have more to repair before you're done.  Unless they just slide out which would be best, it's impossible to tell from that picture.  But if you want to guard against that, you could put up this nice little Rube Goldberg machine:  Get some cheapy 2x3s, clamp one side to the exposed joists and lean the other end on the stone wall.  Attach another piece of 2x3 across them next to the furring wall and attach the furring wall to that cross-piece to hold it in place.

Or you could shim between the furring and the wall, drill through the wood and through the bricks behind it, and attach everything together with long tapcons.  You can remove those when you're done or leave them as extra support.